# Is there a way to create a recurring daily list that can be marked complete daily?

Tags: list

Essentially my team and I have a list of over 100 tasks that have to be completed on a daily basis.

I would like to create a list in that populates every morning (or midnight, or whatever the case may be) with the items that need to be completed. When an associate completes the item its marked as completed or removes itself from the list. Then in a perfect world the list would repopulate the next day.

The main issue I'm having is I'm unable to download SharePoint Designer as our computers are VERY strictly monitored, so I would preferably have to complete this with the basic tools in SharePoint.  If anyone has any ideas i would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in an HTML/JavaScript page that you could upload to a library. The downside is that someone would have to go to the page everyday and push a button to accomplish this.

Another possibility would be to use PowerShell to do this via a Windows scheduled task. But you'd need to get IT involved for this. The upside being it is not a compiled binary so they could read and understand the code and it would run everyday automatically.

Either way, the background steps would be the same. You need to create two task lists. One that will contain the "examples" of the tasks you want to have created. The other will be the actual task list you'll do the work in. This way when you add or remove tasks (next month it's 105 tasks you have to complete), you don't have to modify the code. Let me know which sounds better to you and I can add some code to my answer.